# Matlab: How to get all the possible different matrices by shifting it's rows (Update: each row has a different step)

Tags: matlab, matrix

> Lets say I have a 3x5 matrix
>
> ```
> a=[1 2 4 7 5;
>    3 4 5 6 2;
>    6 7 1 2 3];
> ```
>
> I want to get all the different matrices by shifting it's rows.
>
> The code I wrote is
>
> ```
> a=[1,2,4,7,5;3,4,5,6,2;6,7,1,2,3];
>
> for j=1:3
>
>     for i = 1:5
>
>         a(j,:)=circshift(a(j,:),[i 1]);
>         disp(a)
>     end
> end
> ```
>
> the problem is that I should have 25 different matrices but instead I
>   have 15 (Due to the 5 loops of i in the 3 loops of j) How can I fix
>   it?
>
> Is there a general way to do this (Not for matrices of specific size)

---

(EDIT)

I noticed that this was not efficient for my program (for a 10x24 matrix the results are huge) so I changed the program a bit.
New problem:

Lets say I have a 3x6 matrix

```
a=[1 2 4 7 5 7;
   3 4 5 6 2 9;
   6 7 1 2 3 4];
```

I want to get all the different matrices by shifting it's rows. But the trick is that every row has a different shift step. (defined from value inside a different matrix)

For example:
row 1 has a step of 3 (2 different rows):
 1 2 4 7 5 7 and 7 5 7 1 2 4
row 2 has a step of 2 (3 different rows):
 3 4 5 6 2 9 , 5 6 2 9 3 4 and 2 9 3 4 5 6
and row 3 has a step of 3 (2 different rows):
 6 7 1 2 3 4 and 2 3 4 6 7 1

this means that I should have 2x3x2 = 12 different matrices.

```
a=[1,2,4,7,5,7;3,4,5,6,2,9;6,7,1,2,3,4];
b=[2,3,2];

    for j=1:3
        if b(j) == 2
        for i = 1:2
            a(j,:)=circshift(a(j,:),[i 3]);
            disp(a)
        end
        elseif b(j) == 3
        for i = 1:3
            a(j,:)=circshift(a(j,:),[i 2]);
            disp(a)
        end
    end
```

Is there a way to get my results in a 3x6x12 matrix or a (3*12)x6 matrix?

Comment: Sorry, where does the number 25 come from? Shouldn't there be 125 different matrices given a 3x5 source matrix? Each row has 5 possible arrangements for a total of 5x5x5 = 125 combinations?

Comment: Normally you are correct but in my case after each shift I get the sum of each column. So in my case there is no need for the first row to be shifted. I don't mind if the solution has 125 different matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a recursive function like this:

```
function res = shift_all(a)
res = shift_recurse(a,1,[]);

function res = shift_recurse(a,r,existing)
res = existing;
m = a;
for i = 1:size(a,2)
    if r < size(a,1)
        res = shift_recurse(m, r+1, res);
    elseif r == size(a,1)
        res = cat(3, res, m);
    end
    m(r,:) = circshift(a(r,:),[1 i]);
end
```

And calling `res = shift_all(a)` yields a 3x5x125 matrix of results.

Comment: I tried your code before and there was an error:
"A nested function cannot be defined inside a control statement"

Comment: Works fine in the latest version of MATLAB. I don't have access to anything else.

Comment: This is designed as a function file. you need to save it to file named shift_all.m and the run it from the command line of matlab.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in matlab. Worked like a charm!!! Still need help to adjust it to the new problem.

Comment: Use the `cat` function to concatenate matrices along a given dimension. I use it in my code here to do exactly what you want. `help cat` to read up on it.